# Storing Docker images on SD card

Tags: linux, docker, sd-card, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Docker image I am trying to build on a Jetson TX2. The onboard storage is too small for the image, so I have an SD card I would like to write the image/container to.

How would I go about doing this?

I have tried this solution: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux

however, it causes docker to hang with most operations (docker images, docker container, docker build, etc).

Comment: SD cards are horrible for storage like this. I would recommend using a real USB flash drive instead.

Comment: @JakeGould how would you recommend doing it with a flash drive?

Comment: FWIW, the reason the system hangs is SD cards are not fast when reading or writing. You are using tool that is not appropriate for the task.